# Mongo Aggregate to select some objects of an array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get some objects of an array in mongodb.

I have something like this:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   prop1: "string",
   prop2: 4,
   prop3: [
       { val1: "a", val2: "b" },
       { val1: "c", val2: "d" },
       { val1: "a", val2: "l" },
       { val1: "b", val2: "m" },
       { val1: "j", val2: "k" },
       { val1: "a", val2: "o" }
}
```

And I want to get this result:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   prop1: "string",
   prop2: 4,
   prop3: [
       { val1: "a", val2: "b" },
       { val1: "a", val2: "l" },
       { val1: "a", val2: "o" }
}
```

As I know, `$elemMatch` only return the first matched element, and I would like to get all matched elemets.

I have read something about `$redact (aggregation)` [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), but the only thing that I obtain are some errors.

Answer (score 0):

i am supposing the name of your collection is data

```
  db.data.aggregate([
  {$match:{"prop3.val1":"a"}},
  {$group: {id:"$prop3"}}
  ])
```

I hope this could help you !!

Comment: It's wrong and the duplicate is already accepted by the OP.